# Hero Link is not clickable(not working)

Tags: html, css

I am in the middle of a basic HTML mock-up of a website and i added a clickable button link to the hero area....as i mouse over the button, my mouse doesn't change to the hand or anything, also it is not clickable. However i am able to reference the tag in CSS. HELP! lol

[image: link and hero area]

[image: Trying to see if anything was covering the link]

```
    <div id="hero">
           <div id="herolink">
               <div class="holder">
                   <p>FRIENDS THAT TRAVEL TOGETHER STAY TOGETHER</p>
                   <a href="www.google.com" class="link">THE LINK</a>
               </div>

           </div>
    </div>
```

also hover part of Css is not responding:

```
a.link {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px;
    padding-left: 93px;
    padding-right: 111px;
}



a.link:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: add the `http://` to that href (for one thing). Some browsers don't like it when you leave it out.

Comment: Jamar Flowers, would you like to see what's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can see is a `z-index` issue here. Make the `<a>` `relative`ly positioned and bring it above:

```css
a.link {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-left: 93px;
  padding-right: 111px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100000;
}
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ha ha... Could be.

Comment: Oh well, call it their "Xmas present".

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ha ha... True that! `:D`

Comment: @JamarFlowers Welcome buddy.